# Issue with mvc:annotation-driven and @PathVariable

Tags: spring-mvc

Not sure what I am doing wrong here but when I DO NOT define the `mvc:annotation-driven` in my servlet, the value returned from the `@PathVariable` is not getting displayed in my jsp page and when I do define the annotation-driven, all other links e.g. home gets broken and I get the The specified `HTTP` method is not allowed for the requested resource (Request method `GET` not supported).

```
    @Controller("HealthCheckController")
    @RequestMapping("/healthCheckSummary")

    public class HealthCheckController {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(GolSimpleMappingExceptionResolver.class);
    private HealthCheckService healthCheckService = null;
    private IEappDataAccessFacade dataAccessFacade;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEappStatus(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String password, Model model){

        String dbConnectivityStatus = getDatabaseConnectivityStatus() ? "online" : "offline";

        if (!username.equals("lola") || !password.equals("123")) {
            // wrong credentials were provided
            log.error("The login credentials in the header are not valid." + username + password);
            throw new RuntimeException( "Unable to continue, the login credentials in the header are not valid." + username + password);
        }

        model.addAttribute("healthCheckSummary", dbConnectivityStatus); 

        return "healthCheckSummary";
    }

    public HealthCheckService getHealthCheckService()
    {
        return healthCheckService;
    }

    public boolean getDatabaseConnectivityStatus() {

        String result = “OK”;

        if (result != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Oh and in the application context we have defined the

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

JSP page

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
```

Welcome ${username} - ${password}

Eapp is currently ${healthCheckSummary}

Comment: did not understand your question, pathvariable is something coming from JSP page through form submit or ajax call, are you not able to get values in your controller

Comment: I am trying to print username and password... I am posting my jsp page. Thanks.

Comment: Thats the URL I am using. http://localhost:8080/eapp/healthCheckSummary/lola/123

Comment: please post your context xml also, JSP page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You never put your `username` and `password` `@PathVariable`s in the model. Your jsp page has no way of knowing that they even existed as you lose any reference to them after the code leaves `getEappStatus`. Add the following to your handler method:

   ```
   model.addAttribute("username", username);
   model.addAttribute("password", password);
   ```

   and see if that works.
2. You might want to add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` just to avoid some surprises when you use some spring-mvc annotations. This isn't strictly necessary, but might save you some head scratching when some `@RequestBody` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes adding it to the model did work. Thanks a lot, not sure how I missed that :s One thing I dont understand and maybe you can tell me, is when I add the annotation-driven to the servlet I dont need to add the username and password to the model and my jsp does display the values. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The <mvc:annotation-driven /> isn't strictly necessary but you might want to include it anyway to avoid any surprises when using spring--mvc annotations. Adding variables to model is necessary. I edited the answer.

Comment: Got it... Thanks a lot for your help and explanation. I am still in process of learning spring thats why I am asking questions within question :) Thanks again. --Korda